# Add border around image part of carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm using Owl Carousel as my homepage's slider, but I would like to put a border around the image section of the slider.  If I put an image around the whole owl-theme class- it will also put it around the next and prev buttons.

I also tried putting the border around the "owl-wrapper-outer" class, which is auto generated, but it ends up putting the border around the images inside of the container, and once you scroll to the left, the left side of the border would stay with the image.
Here is the code showing up in the inspector:

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme" style="display: block; opacity: 1;">
<div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
    <div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 4206px; left: 0px; display: block;">
        <div class="owl-item" style="width: 701px;">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/assets/fullimage1.jpg" alt="The Last of us">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-item" style="width: 701px;">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/assets/fullimage2.jpg" alt="GTA V">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-item" style="width: 701px;">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/assets/fullimage3.jpg" alt="Mirror Edge">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-controls clickable">
    <div class="owl-pagination">
        <div class="owl-page active"><span class=""></span>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-page"><span class=""></span>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-page"><span class=""></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-buttons">
        <div class="owl-prev">prev</div>
        <div class="owl-next">next</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle for essentially what I have on my page, and I'm trying to put a border around the image section, but not the "next" and "prev" buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/mX455/6/

Comment: Hmmm, putting the border on owl-wrapper-outer seems to work fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mX455/4/

Comment: Why can't you just add a border to the `#owl-demo` css?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I should have added the type of border I'm using.  Here's an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mX455/6/
Notice how the left border, for example, stays with the first image, so when it slides to the left, the border does as well.

Comment: @BREAUXseidon - See my updated answer. Padding should not be used for functional borders.

Comment: This is tagged with [tag:owl], whose description is "The Web Ontology Language (OWL) is a vocabulary for creating schemas (ontologies), i.e. definitions of classes, properties and the relationships between them.".  This question doesn't have anything to do with [tag:owl].  In the future, please use [tag:owl-carousel]. Additionally, there's no need to put the tag in the title (e.g., the "Owl Carousel:" prefix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a border issue, as the border is working as it's intended. It's a padding issue.

The images are allowed to flow over the padding.

What you'll need to do is update it so it's using both a border AND a solid box shadow.

```
.owl-wrapper-outer {
    border: 8px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px #888888;
    border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/mX455/11/)

Comment: Yeah, I updated my jsfiddle with what I'm trying to pull off for my border.
Here's what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/mX455/6/

Comment: @BREAUXseidon updated my answer to account for your new fiddle =)

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle: It does not work for "inset" shadow.